# How can I fill the NAs using groupby function in Pandas (using Python) when I have more than one column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, fillna

I am trying to fill the NAs in my data frame using the following code and got an error. Can anyone help? Why it is not working? I need to use more than one column (gender and age). With only one column, it works but beyond one column, I have an error

Here is the code:

```
df['NewCol'].fillna(df.groupby(['gender','age'])['grade'].transform('mean'),inplace=True)
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `df ['NewCol']=df ['NewCol']. fillna (df.groupby (['gender', 'age']) ['grade']. transform ('mean'))` or only `df ['NewCol']. fillna (df.groupby (['gender', 'age']) ['grade']. transform ('mean'), inplace = True)`

Comment: Can you add a df[0:4].to_dict() to your question for evaluation?